# Mobile hamburger links are aligned left for some reason

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a mobile hamburger menu on a Wordpress website. For some reason, when I check the mobile view I can see that all elements are aligned left, although I have centered them and even added some CSS to make sure they will be centered. I don't know why they don't appear centered and I wish that someone here will be able to tell me how I can get them to be centered.

This is the menu's HTML:

```
<div id="content-wrap" class="container clr">


        <div id="primary" class="content-area clr">


            <div id="content" class="site-content clr">



<article class="single-library-article clr">

    <div class="entry clr" itemprop="text">
                <div class="elementor elementor-1303 elementor-type-section">
            <div class="elementor-inner">
                <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
                            <section data-id="70032df" class="elementor-element elementor-element-70032df elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-top-section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;,&quot;background_image&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}}" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                <div class="elementor-row">
                <div data-id="14d0f8d4" class="elementor-element elementor-element-14d0f8d4 elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="5fa72fd" class="elementor-element elementor-element-5fa72fd elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#regulation-mobile"><p dir="rtl"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">מהי רגולציה?</span></span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 400;"></span></p></a></h4>       </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="4e7c2bc" class="elementor-element elementor-element-4e7c2bc elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#maya-about-mobile"><p dir="rtl"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">אודות?</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 500;"></span></span></p></a></h4>     </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="45788e2" class="elementor-element elementor-element-45788e2 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#fit-mobile"><p dir="rtl"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">למי זה מתאים?</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 500;"></span></span></p></a></h4>     </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="2a24b44" class="elementor-element elementor-element-2a24b44 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="contact-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#solution-mobile"><p dir="rtl"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">פתרונות</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 500;"></span></span></p></a></h4>      </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="fcd1ddb" class="elementor-element elementor-element-fcd1ddb elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="contact-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#contact-mobile"><p dir="rtl"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">צור קשר</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 500;"></span></span></p></a></h4>       </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </section>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>

</article>

            </div><!-- #content -->


        </div><!-- #primary -->



    </div>
```

I"m unable to edit this HTML because the website was created with a live builder called Elementor, however I can add any HTML, CSS or jQuery easily.

Here's the CSS I have used on the menu itself:

```
.menu-item-text-mobile {
    -webkit-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
-moz-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
-o-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid transparent; 
border-top: 2.11px solid transparent; 
margin-left:50px;
}


#who-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text, 
#who-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text, 
#who-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}
#solutions-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text, 
#solutions-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text, 
#solutions-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}

#regulation-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text, 
#regulation-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text, 
#regulation-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; }
```

and here you can preview mobile view- [www.mayabarber.co.il](http://www.mayabarber.co.il) and see why all menu links align left instead of being centered. I was able to bypass it with some margins, but the text itself is aligned all left.

Thanks!

Comment: `.elementor-nav-menu--dropdown a { justify-content: center; }`

Comment: I added it, it didn't help unfortunately. @ManojKumar
It looks fine in the preview but when I check it out in the mobile it's still aligned left.

Comment: This is what I see: https://prnt.sc/jwxcfi Where do you add the code? Custom CSS feature?

Comment: Try this one

.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title > a{ justify-content: center !important; display: flex !important; }

Comment: Put it inside of a media query: @media(min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 749px){ code above }

Comment: @ManojKumar Custom CSS feature indeed

Comment: @Alejo_Blue
Okay in the beginning it didn't work, but then I added it to the theme's CSS stylesheet (instead of the live builder's CSS function) and it solved it!

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Now I can see that below the links in the menu, the phone number and the icons I have inserted break and don't remain in the same line. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: @RoziBuber you mean that the phone number & icons are not displayed in the mobile menu?

Comment: Also i see you used my code to fix your issue. Then why you marked @ZohirSalk answer as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `dir="rtl"` on the `<p>` which makes the text goes from right to left, and css styling doesn't override that.

Then add

```
.elementor-heading-title{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Or any other way you see fit to center them.

```css
.menu-item-text-mobile {
  -webkit-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
  transition: border 200ms ease-out;
  border-bottom: 2.11px solid transparent;
  border-top: 2.11px solid transparent;
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#who-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text,
#who-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text,
#who-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text {
  border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
  border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
}

#solutions-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text,
#solutions-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text,
#solutions-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text {
  border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
  border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
}

#regulation-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text,
#regulation-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text,
#regulation-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text {
  border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
  border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
}

.elementor-heading-title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrap" class="container clr">
  <div id="primary" class="content-area clr">
    <div id="content" class="site-content clr">
      <article class="single-library-article clr">
        <div class="entry clr" itemprop="text">
          <div class="elementor elementor-1303 elementor-type-section">
            <div class="elementor-inner">
              <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
                <section data-id="70032df" class="elementor-element elementor-element-70032df elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-top-section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;,&quot;background_image&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}}"
                  data-element_type="section">
                  <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-row">
                      <div data-id="14d0f8d4" class="elementor-element elementor-element-14d0f8d4 elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
                        <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                          <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                            <div data-id="5fa72fd" class="elementor-element elementor-element-5fa72fd elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                              <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
                                  <a href="#regulation-mobile">
                                    <p><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">מהי רגולציה?</span></span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 400;"></span></p>
                                  </a>
                                </h4>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-id="4e7c2bc" class="elementor-element elementor-element-4e7c2bc elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                              <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
                                  <a href="#maya-about-mobile">
                                    <p><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">אודות?</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 500;"></span></span>
                                    </p>
                                  </a>
                                </h4>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-id="45788e2" class="elementor-element elementor-element-45788e2 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                              <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
                                  <a href="#fit-mobile">
                                    <p><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">למי זה מתאים?</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 500;"></span></span>
                                    </p>
                                  </a>
                                </h4>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-id="2a24b44" class="elementor-element elementor-element-2a24b44 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="contact-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                              <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
                                  <a href="#solution-mobile">
                                    <p><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">פתרונות</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 500;"></span></span>
                                    </p>
                                  </a>
                                </h4>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-id="fcd1ddb" class="elementor-element elementor-element-fcd1ddb elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="contact-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                              <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
                                  <a href="#contact-mobile">
                                    <p><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">צור קשר</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 500;"></span></span>
                                    </p>
                                  </a>
                                </h4>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
    <!-- #content -->
  </div>
  <!-- #primary -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I can see that below the links in the menu, the phone number and the icons I have inserted break and don't remain in the same line. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you try, to explain it again, maybe add a picture of the issue.

Comment: I don't understand the new issue too. But it is always better to open a new question for the that.